# Joining on a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am attempting to find distinct values of binnum. I need to however keep origrec within the select as it is a unique id. It doesn't matter what the origrec value is as long as there is one that is tied to the distinct bin.

I am attempting to do this in a join. However, I seem to still be getting all of the values when doing a sub query inner join. Where am I going wrong, and what is the best way to correct this?

Full Code:

```
SELECT distinct d.BINNUM
    , d.LOCATIONNAME
    , d.LOCATIONTYPE
    , d.ORIGREC 
FROM DLOCATION D 
inner join 
( 
    SELECT distinct d1.binnum 
    FROM dlocation d1 
    GROUP BY d1.binnum
) as D1 On d.binnum = d1.binnum
```

First Query:

```
SELECT distinct d.BINNUM,d.LOCATIONNAME,d.LOCATIONTYPE,d.ORIGREC FROM DLOCATION D
```

Would Return:

```
BINNUM  LOCATIONNAME    LOCATIONTYPE    ORIGREC
1       Bruker          RawMaterial     31
1       Bruker          RawMaterial     32
200     WetChem         RawMaterial     33
200     WetChem         RawMaterial     34
555     WetChem         RawMaterial     19
555     WetChem         RawMaterial     21
555     WetChem         RawMaterial     23
555     WetChem         RawMaterial     30
998     WetChem         RawMaterial     26
1002    Forage Cooler   Forage          27
2008    XRF Press       International   29
2009    Long Term       International   28
```

Second Query:

```
SELECT distinct d1.binnum FROM dlocation d1 GROUP BY d1.binnum
```

Would Return:

```
BINNUM
1
200
555
998
1002
2008
2009
```

Why does a inner join still give all the results between these two?

```
BINNUM  LOCATIONNAME    LOCATIONTYPE    ORIGREC
1       Bruker          RawMaterial     31
1       Bruker          RawMaterial     32
200     WetChem         RawMaterial     33
200     WetChem         RawMaterial     34
555     WetChem         RawMaterial     19
555     WetChem         RawMaterial     21
555     WetChem         RawMaterial     23
555     WetChem         RawMaterial     30
998     WetChem         RawMaterial     26
1002    Forage Cooler   Forage          27
2008    XRF Press       International   29
2009    Long Term       International   28
```

How can I only get the BinNum values seen in the second query so it would look like this?

```
BINNUM  LOCATIONNAME    LOCATIONTYPE    ORIGREC
1       Bruker          RawMaterial     31
200     WetChem         RawMaterial     33
555     WetChem         RawMaterial     19
998     WetChem         RawMaterial     26
1002    Forage Cooler   Forage          27
2008    XRF Press       International   29
2009    Long Term       International   28
```

Comment: Take out the ORIGREC column? You have distinct in your query and the values in those rows are different. Also, in your subquery you have distinct AND group by. That is redundant.

Comment: I am in need of the ORIGREC column as described above. This is due to me working within software which requires this column to be present at all times.

Comment: OK. So in your query which one do you want? MIN, MAX?

Comment: It doesn't matter as long as I can list a BINNUM distinctly with any origrec that is tied to one of those BINNUMs. You can refer to the last output example shown in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some basic aggregation can do this. There is no need for a subquery here either. Unless maybe you have a case sensitive collation and DLOCATION and dlocation are actually different tables. Assuming you that is not the case this can be greatly simplified.

```
SELECT d.BINNUM
    , d.LOCATIONNAME
    , d.LOCATIONTYPE
    , MIN(d.ORIGREC)
FROM DLOCATION D 
GROUP BY d.BINNUM
    , d.LOCATIONNAME
    , d.LOCATIONTYPE
```

Comment: It looks as if I over complicated things. Thank you for the clarification :)

Comment: Glad that works for you. Sometimes it just takes a second person to look at something. :)